# Velocity in Perpendicular Electric and Magnetic Fields

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, vectors, dynamical-systems, vector-fields

I've been trying to work this out for a few days now and have got nowhere, hopefully someone here can help!

*In a system with a uniform electric field in the Y direction, and a uniform magnetic field in the Z direction: Find an expression for the initial velocity u, such that the particle travels in a straight line at a constant speed.*

I know that F = q(E + (V x B)), but can't really see how to go about this.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Hint: "straight line at constant speed" = $\vec{a} = 0 \implies \sum \vec{F} = 0$ by Newton's Law. This means $\vec{E} + \vec{v} \times \vec{B} = 0$. Can you proceed from here?

Comment: Write $\vec v=v_x\hat x+v_y\hat y+v_z\hat z$. Then $\vec E=e\hat y$, and $\vec B=B\hat z$. Calculate teh components of $\vec F$. All of them should be zero.